# Is my avatar offensive / a poor choice?

Tags: support, objectivity

Just occurred to me. For a Christian website, is an anime character dressed as an angel a poor choice in an avatar?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not to me (though i won't speak for others on this site). And it would not meet the guidelines for removal as far as SE is concerned.

Comment: Thanks ;) It would be a bit more of a person-person basis, but your message combined with no immediate (negative) answers makes me think it's fine ;)